# ifdef style conditional inclusions for shell

Tags: shell-script

Consider the following script.

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                   

echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - blank.pdf
cp blank.pdf blank2.pdf

pdftk \
    A=blank.pdf `#first file` \
    B=blank2.pdf `#second file` \
    cat A B \
    output b.pdf
```

But suppose I want a variant:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                   

echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - newblank.pdf
cp newblank.pdf newblank2.pdf

pdftk \
    A=newblank.pdf `#first file revised` \
    B=newblank2.pdf `#second file revised` \
    cat A B \
    output b.pdf
```

Now, suppose I want them together. I can do

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                   

echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - blank.pdf
cp blank.pdf blank2.pdf
cp blank.pdf newblank.pdf
cp blank.pdf newblank2.pdf

pdftk \
    A=blank.pdf `#first file` \
    `#A=newblank.pdf` `#first file revised` \
    B=blank2.pdf `#second file` \
    `#B=newblank2.pdf` `#second file revised` \
    cat A B \
    output b.pdf
```

But if I want to switch back and forth between versions, I have to
comment and uncomment stuff. Is there some way I can do a conditional
inclusion, so that I can (say) get one version depending on whether a variable is defined or not, in the style of the `#ifdef` C macro?

It would be nice to have a portable shell solution, but if not, a bash specific one would work too.

Finally, I just use two files in this example (`blank.pdf`. `blank2.pdf`), but I need a solution that works with arbitrary numbers of files. Also, a version that has the old and new versions of each file next to each other for comparison purposes would be preferable. Also, some of the files might be the same in both the original and new versions, so it would be good not to have to repeat those in that case.

Comment: yeah - you could just use `#ifdef`. `m4` will happily expand macros in input to output regardless of how you plan to use it.

Comment: @mikeserv Could you provide an example? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the difference would be between #ifdef inclusion and regular `if then` in a shell script. Is it that you want to include/exclude text in the middle of a command?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I'm not particular on the implementation, but basically I want to be able to switch back and forth between the first two versions, using a single script, and with minimal fuss. I'm certainly open to the idea of using `m4` for example, though I'd not considered the possibility.

Comment: `if [ "$USE_NEW" ] ; then pdftk .. A=newblank.pdf ; else pdftk ... A=blank.pdf ; fi`

Comment: You can define bash variable and it them with `if [ -z ${var+x} ]` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601515/how-to-check-if-a-variable-is-set-in-bash

Comment: @FaheemMitha - it's just a preprocessor. `echo 'ifdef(`thing'\'',`something else'\'')' | m4 -Dthing=not\ that
something else`

Comment: @MichaelHomer That would work, but I'd like the old and the new versions next to each other.

Comment: hmm... well, it's a preprocessor. so it can work your shell script, too, just as it would a c source. it might take some getting used to because you'll need to `changequote` probably - the backticks won't fly in a shell script - but if they're behind comments it doesn't really matter. anyway, i was just suggesting because you said you knew it - and you *can* do it. so do whatever you like - it was only a suggestion.

Comment: In this kind of situation I generally set one or more global variables that identify particular features or capabilities at the top of my code, and use those in an `if`...`else`...`fi` block. Where realistic I prefer to identify by feature presence rather than by OS type (Cygwin, Linux, Unix, etc.)

Comment: Is your main problem commenting out lines? if so, why you don't write a shell script that does the job? For example, something like this `$ comment "=newblank.pdf" filename` that comments each line containing `=newblank.pdf` in `filename`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the versions you gave are only different filenames/arguments.

Differentiating variants of more or less the same code with "`ifdef`"-like structures is usually not the best way, as it lead to
hardly maintainable and duplicated code.

In your example case, you can for example use shell variables (and one small `if ... ; then` clause) to switch between two variants:

```
 #call the script with -2 to switch to the second version.
 if [ "$1" = "-2" ]; then
           firstfile="newblank.pdf"
           secondfile="newblank2.pdf"   
 else
           firstfile="blank.pdf"
           secondfile="blank2.pdf"   
fi

echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - "$infile"
cp "$firstfile" "$secondfile"

pdftk \
    "A=$firstfile" `#first file` \
    "B=$secondfile" `#second file` \
    cat A B \
    output b.pdf
```

If you want to have multiple calls of the same code with only slightly changes, you might to consider to define [`functions`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) and call them
with different arguments.

Comment: Well, I want to be able to do this for arbitrary numbers of files.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The approach for multiple files are the same. You just need to adjust the logic how you fill the shell variables. You can for example use the command line arguments `$1` `$2` directly.

Comment: Ok, noted. I was confused by your `infile`, `outfile` nomenclature.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the answer. I'll take a look.

Comment: Without the -2, I get " [: =: unary operator expected". I think the test requires a little adjustment. I think quoting `$1`, i.e. `"$1"`, fixes it.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thanks for the hint, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To get an argument as a condition of value definition, you can just conditionally expand the value.

```
unset var
echo  ${var+" nothing because this is unset "}
var=
echo  ${var-" nothing because the value is null but the var is set "}
var=value
echo  ${var:+" this will expand    -    to my optionally provided word "}
```

The `:+` form will expand to *word* when a variable is both set and not null. `:-` will expand to *word* when it is either unset or null - else it expands to its value otherwise. The `[+-]` forms without the colon are similar but drop any condition on null values and only tesr a parameter for whether it is set.

If you had an argument list like:

```
pdftk \
    arg arg ${first+"`#first file ${rev+revised}`"} \
    ${blank+"blankfile"} ${second+"`#second file ${rev+revised}`"}
```

... you might could make it work...

```
echo "" | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 - "${pre+${age:=new}}blank.pdf"
cp "${pre+$age}blank.pdf" "${pre+$age}blank2.pdf"

pdftk \
    "A=${pre+$age}blank.pdf" "`#first file${rev:+ revised: $rev}`" \
    "B=${pre+$age}blank2.pdf" "`#second file${rev:+ revised: $rev}`" \
    cat A B \
    output b.pdf
```

Because they nest you can optionally expand a value within a value. So...

```
pre=+ rev=$(date) age=old your_script
```

...would work out a lot different than...

```
unset pre rev age; your_script
```

Comment: A complete example would be helpful. This does not use m4 then?

Comment: I've been trying to get this going with multiple arguments at each site and `"$@"`, but I can't reset the parameters multiple times within the command and have it take effect before the expansions, so you have to repeat the tests. If you're bash-only you can just use named arrays though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - it works like `m4` more than a shell's a conditionals because it expands like `m4` does.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: `${var+"$@"}`. it's also a good use case for `eval` in many cases - especially in that all you need to do is `#` comment with the expansion.

Comment: Yes, but I only get one `$@` for the entire command, and there's two different sites with unique arguments to include.

Comment: @MichaelHomer - yeah, you can split them with `$IFS`: `${var+"$whole"$IFS"whole"}` but that could be annoying. Like I said, `eval` is good for this if you plan it right, and yeah, you can use named arrays - and introspect a little further with math in their indexes. in `ksh` you get an actual different quote region. `echo "${not+" quoted in here " quoted in here}"`